# How to deal with this StaleElementReferenceException in Selenium?

Tags: python, django, selenium

I'm currently going through an intro to Django/TDD book and I've hit a StaleElementReferenceException and got stuck.  I've been googling around and searching StackOverflow for a solution to my error, but I haven't been able to work around it.  My relevant code is as follows:

**functional_tests.py**

```
inputbox.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
self.browser.implicitly_wait(3)
table = self.browser.find_element_by_id('id_list_table')
#rows = table.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr')
rows_ref = lambda: table.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr')
#self.browser.implicitly_wait(3)
foundBuy = False
for row in rows_ref():
    self.browser.implicitly_wait(3)
    rows_text = row.text
    if (rows_text == '1: Buy peacock feathers'):
        foundBuy = True
        break
if not (foundBuy):
    self.fail('Could not find "1: Buy peacock feathers" in rows\' text')
#self.assertIn('1: Buy peacock feathers', [row.text for row in rows_ref()])
```

The error occurs in the above code at the "rows_text = row.text" line of code.  In my original code, it occurred in the commented out self.assertIn statement at the bottom.

**home.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>To-Do lists</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Your To-Do list</h1>
        <form method="POST">
            <input name="item_text" id="id_new_item" placeholder="Enter a to-do item"/>
            {% csrf_token %}
        </form>
        <table id="id_list_table">
            {% for item in items %}
                <tr><td>{{ forloop.counter }}: {{ item.text }}</td></tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

The original code the book has me enter is commented out (minus the one implicity_wait).  In my previous time going through this book, the code worked no problem, but I have been getting this StaleElement error non-stop and cannot figure out a way to get past it.  Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would like to point out that the implicit wait is not what many people think is. In your code it looks like you are using it as a kind of sleep - but it is far from that. Implicit wait simply tries again for this amount of seconds if it can't find an element. If it finds at least one the first time, it has no effect. It is enough to set it once, and then it will be valid for each element lookup during the whole session. But it is not suitable to use it for waiting for special conditions.

What seems to happen here is the following (kind of race condition):

- You press Enter
- Before the page would be updated, the driver finds all currently available elements
- You try to loop through the elements, but the page is updated meanwhile, making your previous finds invalid.

This all happens in a fraction of a second.

You can use an actual sleep after pressing Enter key (not a recommended solution, but for experimenting it works) or you can wait for the actual action to happen/finish. (For example you can use a custom condition that counts the current number of rows, and waits until it changes, or use a javascript that waits until all post requests finish.)